# Graph Traversal Algorithm with discount

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I have a directed graph with weighted edges and I would like to find the all pairs shortest paths in my graph. But I want to be able to take discounts into consideration.

For example:

```
A->B    with weight 10
A->C    with weight 20
B->C    with weight 10
C->D    with weight 10
A->B->C with weight 15 because I get a discount of 5 if and only if I visit B first. (see clarification)

A->B->C->D should therefor have weight 25 while
A->C->D    with weight 30
```

Is there a way to implement this? I have looked at various algorithms (Floyd-Warshall etc) but they dont seem to recognize this problem...

edit: to clarify: Only the combination (A->B->C) gets the discount.

```
E->(A->B->C)->F gets it because it has the exact combination in its path, but 
A->E->B->C      does not get it
```

Comment: Do you get the discount if you go `A->E->B->F->C`?

Comment: No, the discount is only applied if it is A->B->C

Comment: This is still an inadequate problem definition.  How exactly is the set of all discounts described?  The phrase "if I visit B first" has many different possible meanings.

Comment: In what situation would the edge B->C actually cost 10?

Comment: Updated (and hopefully)clarified the question. B->C costs 10 e.g. if you have B->C->D (total of 20)

Comment: Why can't you just add a shortcut to `A->C` and every other discounted subpath?

Comment: Because (I think) it will only find the solution if I look for A->C but not if I look for A->B->C. Or lets say I need to have A->B->C, but:

`A->C is 14`,
`A->B is 10`,
`B->C is 10`,
`A->B->C is 15`,

Then `A->B->C` is not an optimal solution for `A->C`, only for `A->B->C`

Comment: So it's not actually all-pairs shortest paths, but shortest paths with waypoints?

Comment: I did not know that was the name of it, sorry :)

Comment: How many discounted paths are there? Can the path length of discounted paths be any length?

Comment: the length of the discounted path is always of the form `A->B->C`. I would say about 1/2 of the paths will be discounted

Answer (score 2):

You can augment your graph by adding edges and dummy nodes to represent the discounts. For instance, if you have a discount for the path `A->B->C`, add a new node `B'` with **only** the edges:

```
A->B'
B'->C
```

such that

```
w(A,B') + w(B',C) = w(A,B) + w(B,C) - discount
```

where `w(S,T)` is the weight of edge `S->T`. It doesn't matter which edge you apply the discount to, so you could have

```
w(A,B') = 10, w(B',C) = 5, or
w(A,B') = 5 , w(B',C) = 10
```

Note that if you have a node `Q` where the only edges incident on `Q` in the original graph are:

```
S->Q
Q->T
```

and a discount is to be applied for the path `S->Q->T`, adding a new node `Q'` is redundant.  You can safely apply the discount to the original graph. If you add the dummy node anyway, it won't cause the results to be erroneous, or even any different, it will just add unnecessary nodes to the search.

Obviously, in the output of your paths you should treat any dummy node as their original counterpart, i.e. a path of `A->B'->C` should be reported as `A->B->C`.

Comment: I think this could work. I will try it out on monday. Thank you very much!